# progressive web app external domain link other than base start_url

Tags: google-chrome, manifest, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

In my progressive app the 
"start_url" : https://view.abc.com opens fine, 
but there is an other link on "start_url" landing page, which is redirecting to https://view.xyz.com opens in an app but the browser url and title shows in PWA. is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Read it through again and try to improve it a bit :-)

Comment: add the code lines for start_url and redirect_url. Are you using redirect or sendFile